# Toggling CheckBox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, addeventlistener

```html
      <form>

  Age: <input type="checkbox" class="first" value="Below 10">Below 10
   <input type="checkbox" class="first" value="Below 20"> Below 20
   <input type="checkbox" class="first" value="Below 30">Below 30
   <br>

   You have clicked: 
  <span id="maClass">
   
  </span>

   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var maClass = document.querySelector("#maClass");
   var first = document.querySelectorAll(".first");

   var isClicked = false;
   var i=0;
   for(i; i<first.length ; i++){

     first[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
 
    if(isClicked){
     maClass.style.display = "none";
     isClicked = false;
    }else{
     maClass.style.display = "inline";
     maClass.style.display = first[i].getAttribute("value");
     isClicked = true; 
       }

     });
      }
   </script>
```

I tried to make these 3 checkboxes toggle.
I used eventListener in Javascript.
I used same class name for 3 different checkboxes.
This is because, it will help me to store whole decision into one array.
But it doesn't work
**I cannot make it toggle.
Please help**

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *I cannot make it toggle*. Make what toggle? When should the toggle occur?

Comment: changing a variable from false to true or back makes no change to your checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you are trying to do is change the value of `<span id="maClass">` on clicking the checkboxes.

You should actually use radio buttons if you don't want them all to be selected at the same time. And it can have a much simpler JS code (for example, no need to save `isClicked` or things like that).

Here is the updated code:

```html
<body>
  <form>

    Age: <input type="radio" name="first" class="first" value="Below 10">Below 10
        <input type="radio" name="first" class="first" value="Below 20"> Below 20
        <input type="radio" name="first" class="first" value="Below 30">Below 30
        <br>

        You have clicked: 
    <span id="maClass">

    </span>

  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var maClass = document.querySelector("#maClass");
        var first = document.querySelectorAll(".first");

        var i=0;
        for(i; i<first.length ; i++){

          first[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                maClass.innerHTML = e.target.value;
          });
        }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir. 
You have saved my time today.
"Have a Good Day Sir"

Comment: Glad to know it helped you. Please accept it as the correct answer if that solved your problem :)

Comment: I have another question, Also.
If i choose any checkbox(not radio button)  can i get it's value extracted too?
And use it for other purposes.
Like in previous radio button?

Comment: @ArjunBhat Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks Alot.
"You are always helpful."